# How do I add an HTML tag to all pages on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I just want to add 1 `<div>` to every page on a wordpress site. I know I could just open every page and add it over and over, but that's not a good option when the site has over 80 pages.

Is there a way for me to add the HTML once and have it apply to every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to `header.php` or`footer.php` or any other template file thats included on every page